# uninstalled gnome-extensions are back after reboot

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I was about to uninstall few gnome-extensions from my desktop so at https://extensions.gnome.org/ (it is probably standard way) I had first to update it (uninstall button is not available before update) then uninstall. Everything looked fine and it was removed from installed list and its components was removed from my desktop.

However after reboot extensions are back again. And ask to update again. How to remove it completely?
Where are extensions stored? They are not listed in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ but still active and its components shown on desktop after reboot...

thank you

Comment: Select the extensions app which is pre-installed in ubuntu and try uninstalling it from there

Comment: Thank you for you response, @Heisenberg, however it is almost the same with little difference. Extensions which I have to update are in "Built-In" section of Extensions Application without ability to uninstall. In application there is not possibility to update so I update it from http://extensions.gnome.org After update extension is automagically moved to "Manually installed" in app and I am able to uninstall it... However, after reboot it is back and requires update...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those extensions were installed globally in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

It is not nice but I had to manually remove it there...